# Smarty 3 number_format in template works wrong

Tags: php, smarty3

I use smarty 3 template engine in php. I use this code inside my template:

```
{$cart_sum_total*$smarty.const.CURRENCY_HOME_RATE|number_format:2:".":","}
```

$cart_sum_total has value 85.92
$smarty.const.CURRENCY_HOME_RATE has value 44.1623

The template shows 3794.2272

Why do I have 4 decimal points? I tell smarty to have 2 decimal points. What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Put your statement before |number_format in brackets.
The modifier seems to have precedence before multiplication, as 44.16*85.92 = 3794.2272.

```
{($cart_sum_total*$smarty.const.CURRENCY_HOME_RATE)|number_format:2:".":","}
```